# How to send multiple JSON objects in one rest api post?

Tags: node.js

I am looking at this example how to send or post multiple Json objects. I wanted to pass an entity type model but not sure how using.

`src-> modelfile`

````
  ```          const groupid = req.body.groupid;
   ```         const device_id = req.body.device_id;
    ```        const nearbytime = req.body.nearbytime;
      ```      const distance = req.body.distance;
       ```     const lat = req.body.lat;
            const lon = req.body.lon;
            const user_id = req.body.user_id;
            const sql = 'INSERT INTO tb_token SET  device_id=?, user_id=?, groupid=?, nearbytime=?, distance=?, lat=?, lon=?';
    
            return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => { 
                connection.query (sql, [device_id,user_id,groupid,nearbytime,distance,lat,lon], (err, response) => {
                        if (!err) {
                            resolve (response);
                        } else {
                            reject (err);
                        }
                    }
                );
            });    
        },
    
    
    
    ```
````

Comment: {
"status": 400,
"error": " deviceid required"
}                                            {
"status": 400,
"error": " deviceid required"
}

Answer (score 0):

you can enter multiple records at the same time. example
INSERT INTO
tb_token(device_id, user_id, groupid, nearbytime, distance, lat, lon)
VALUES
(1.10, 11, 2020-10-10, 50, -24.6, -35),
(1.10, 11, 2020-10-10, 50, -24.6, -35 ​),
(1.10, 11, 2020-10-10, 50, -24.6, -35 ​),
(1.10, 11, 2020-10-10, 50, -24.6, -35 ​),

values ​​are the records you want to insert in the table, you just need to organize them correctly

Comment: i did but i go error {
"status": 400,
"error": " deviceid required"
}

Comment: apparently it's a typo, you're expecting deviceid and it's probably sending device_id.